# Loop inside a loop in javaScript printing more than required values

Tags: loops, double

I need to print a month calendar selecting from drop down select options of months.I used double while loop to create table (one for rows and 2nd to populate rows with days). the problem is my code is printing days upto 35 for all months except 28 for February.

```js
  var list1 = document.getElementById("list1");

list1.onclick = function(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById("monthCal");
    div1.innerHTML="";
    populateMonth(this.selectedIndex);
    console.log(this.selectedIndex);  
};

function how_many_days(month){
    switch (month){
        case 0:
        case 2:
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            days_of_month=31;
            break;
        case 10:
        case 8:
        case 5:
        case 3:
            days_of_month=30;
            break;
        case 1:
            days_of_month=28;
            break;
    }
    return days_of_month;
}

function populateMonth(monthindex){



        var writeTo =document.getElementById("monthCal");


        var table123 = document.createElement("table");
        var tbody123 = document.createElement("tbody");




      var days= how_many_days(monthindex);
        var i =1;
        while(i<days){
            var j=0;
            var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
            while(j<7){
                var tableData = document.createElement("td");
                var txtNode = document.createTextNode(i+"");
                tableData.appendChild(txtNode);
                tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
                ++j;
                ++i;
            }
            tbody123.appendChild(tableRow);
        }

        var conatiner1 = document.getElementById("monthCal");

        table123.appendChild(tbody123);
        conatiner1.appendChild(table123);


    }
```

```html
Year: <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
Month:<select id="list1">
    <option id="month1" value="Jan">January</option>
    <option id="month2" value="Feb">Feburary</option>
    <option id="month3" value="March" selected>March</option>
    <option id="month4" value="April">April</option>
    <option id="month5" value="May">May</option>
    <option id="month6" value="June">June</option>
    <option id="month7" value="July" >July</option>
    <option id="month8" value="Aug">August</option>
    <option id="month9" value="sept">September</option>
    <option id="month10" value="oct">October</option>
    <option id="month11" value="Nov">November</option>
    <option id="month12" value="Dec">December</option>
</select><hr>

<div id="monthCal">

</div>
```

Comment: `while (j<7)` will always do 7 cells. You need to add a condition for also `i` there so you stop at the end.

Comment: #Sami thanks for rapid response but I will very indebted if u give me code snippet..

Comment: Use the same condition for `i` as in the outer loop and combine with and operator, then it will stop correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since your inner loop will always go to 7, you will only get number of days divisible by 7. You have to cut the inner loop short when needed, so use the same condition for `i` as in the outer loop.

So change `while (j<7)` into `while ((j<7) && (i<days))` and the inner loop will cut short when needed.

Comment: thnks dear it worked for me..but a little problem here  for the month of Feb it still print 28 days (Leap year).